# Chrome network requests stall for exactly 10 seconds when using custom local SSL hostnames and certificates

Tags: google-chrome, dns, ssl, certificate

I develop websites locally with [mkcert](https://github.com/FiloSottile/mkcert) tool to create SSL certificates for my domain (eg `project.local`). Then I point `project.local` to 127.0.0.1 in my hosts file (/private/etc/hosts for me on Mac). I require this set up to do cross domain cookie with a root domain, since they don't work on `localhost`.

Either way, with this setup, most network requests to my custom local domain are "stalled" for almost exactly 10 seconds in chrome every time. An example is below. It makes debugging and rapidly iterating on my projects extremely time consuming when it constantly stalls for 10 seconds at a time. I'm sure this has to do with my local domain and certs, but I don't know why or how to tell chrome to stop doing that. Any ideas?

[image].

Comment: Are there other requests running at the same time? Proxy? There are only a couple documented reasons for the Stalled\Queued status, and it's mostly Chrome waiting due to concurrency limits: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/reference/?utm_source=devtools#timing-explanation

Comment: No, this occurs even with a single tab open and on the first HTTP request (no other requests occuring to the origin). It seems to be time based. It occurs on the first connection to the origin, then subsequent page refreshes do not get stalled. If I wait 30s or so before refreshing, it gets stalled again.

Comment: Changing the host to `project.localhost` solved the issue. It seems to be a problem with *.local but I'm not sure why. I noticed the Mac proxy settings say that "*local" bypasses proxy settings, so maybe its a special case (although I don't have any proxies configured anyway).

Comment: yeah `.local` is reserved for mDNS (and bonjour in MacOS). It's good practice to avoid, since the OS will always attempt discovery instead of checking `/hosts` first. 10 seconds still seems like a weird timeout for those, but maybe Chrome cuts it off there manually.